# Applications of $p$-adic Hodge theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

I am trying to learn $p$-adic Hodge theory. I found some materials explaining main theorems (or aspects) of the theory. However, I could not find references which explaining how to use the theory. Especially, I would like to know geometric/arithmetic applications, if there are, of $p$-adic Hodge theory in number theory. Since I did not specify meaning of the words 'geometric/arithmetic', any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd imagine this would work better if it was made communiti-wiki, and one application per answer.

Comment: Have you looked at http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/notes.pdf?

Comment: The notes by Brinon and Conrad are great, but I personally didn't get much motivation out of them. "An abelian variety has good reduction if and only if the associated Galois rep is crystalline" didn't seem to me like a good enough "application", as the definition of "crystalline" is complicated. I'd love to see here, say, new theorems about varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ proved using $p$-adic comparison theorems.

Comment: @Piotr I guess you're right. I'm not a specialist in arithmetic geometry, and I don't think I can be of much help here. :-)

Comment: One type of application of p-adic Hodge theory, including some integral Hodge theory, which gives crisp statements is to the study of smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$ with everywhere good reduction (or very little ramification). The earliest result of this kind is Fontaine's theorem: there is no abelian variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ with everywhere good reduction, but there are generalizations due to Fontaine and Abrashkin. See e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.2905.

Comment: Some of the world experts in this area are Christophe Breuil, Frank Calegari, Pierre Colmez, Toby Gee, Mark Kisin, Peter Scholze, and Richard Taylor.  Have you tried looking at their work (say by visiting their web-pages)?

Comment: It plays a key role in proving modularity lifting theorems by making possible the study of local deformation rings for an l-adic representation at p=l. One can look at the section on Fontaine-Laffaille modules in Darmon-Diamond-Taylor for the start of this story I guess.

Comment: Dear @tracing, first of all, I do not want to be offensive (I am worried about my poor English makes you angry). Of course, I know that I can learn things on the theory through reading experts' works, and maybe that is the only way that I can do at this moment. However, at least for me, it seems quite far from getting intution on the theory for applications.

Comment: @Kevin.lijh: You won't make me angry!  I don't mean to read through their works; but you can read the titles and introductions to their papers.  This is a sensible and standard way to learn what people are doing in mathematics.  E.g. if you look at Taylor's papers, you will see his main focus is on proving theorems relating Galois reps. and automorphic forms, and that Sato--Tate was one big application.  If you look at Kisin's papers, you will see that he was also focused on modularity, and now is focused on integral models of Shimura varieties.  Both authors use a lot of p-adic Hodge theory.

Answer (score 7):

For an example of an application of $p$-adic Hodge theory in a geometric setting, I thoroughly recommend reading the beautiful paper

P. Berthelot, H. Esnault, K. Rulling, *Rational points over finite fields for regular models of algebraic varieties of Hodge type $\geq 1$*, Ann. of Math. (2) $\bf{176}$ 2012, no. 1, 413-508.

The result is nice and concrete: they prove congruences for the number of rational points on such varieties. As you will see, the proof makes use of a nice range of big theorems from $p$-adic Hodge theory and is very clearly explained.